# custom swing component problem with constructor

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

i am a java beginner.i had built a java program MyCalculaterGuI in notepad,compiled and run it on commond prompt.now i am using netbeans 11.1.i have created a jar file of MyCalculterGUI.class by commond prompt.it runs,works fine.now when i want to add MyCalculater.jar file in my netbeans swing controls as a custom component so that i reuse it
by just drag and drop in any JFrame form.first i added this jar file in my gradle project custom library 'libs' folder which is included in project dependencies.then i added this jar file into swing control by pallete manager.MyCalculater.jar is added in swing control.but when i drag and drop it.it gives following error.
component instantiation error
failed to create an instance of pkg/MyCalculaterGUI class
the class itself was loaded but intantiating failed.this usualy happens due to exception in constructor or initializer code ...........
following is only constructor in my class .

public MyCalculaterGUI()

{

initGUI();

}

now please tell me how should it look like to solve the above mentioned problem.
regards

Comment: initGUI failed; Its IN THE CONSTRUCTOR isnt it?

Comment: yes it is initiaization of GUI.if this call should not be in constructor than where should i put it.

Comment: I have also tried this. public MyCalculaterGUI()

{

} and then in main method  javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
initGUI();
}
}); this results no error but when I drag and drop it only a vacant panel is drawn not calculater.